# 3 month rolling/moving average

Tags: mysql

Somehow this is not the initial request I have put forward. Indeed there are similar requests however as per my previous and initial message I tried the examples already delivered and some how I am failing to understand the concept.

What I want is a 3-month rolling average on the price.

The table title tbl consisting of the following productID, priceMonth, Price

The SQL statement I am using is the following:

```
SELECT AVG(Price) over(partition by productID between 2 preceding and current row) 
as rolling_avg 
FROM tbl 
GROUP by priceMonth 
order by price
```

I am not sure if the syntax is correct as it is giving me the following error:

> An alias was previously found. (near "rolling_avg").

Therefore I cordially ask you the following:

1) I cannot locate where the alias problem is, can I cordially ask your assistance?

2) Is the above sql statements addresses what I am looking for? i.e a 3month rolling average?

Comment: Is this for MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Hi tadam its for MySQL... apologies if I did not detail that aspect

Comment: Please remove the sql-server tag if this is for MySQL.

Comment: While you're at it, remove the superfluous PHP tag too.

Comment: Removed both, thanks!

Comment: Mysql does not support the `over` expression.

Comment: dear shadow thanks this is already an indication, is there something similar in mySQL?